# Fetch the Django Serializer Indirectly

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am having a circular dependency problem. In order to avoid that I am using

```
apps.get_model('ModelName')
```

Is there a way to fetch the serializer class in the same way?

Comment: I don't think that such a thing is implemented in the django rest framework, since you may define several serializers for the same model, and in that case the `get_serializer` method wouldn't know what serializer to user.

If you have one serializer per model as convention, you may build such a "registry" yourself.

On the other hand, circular dependencies may be solved in an another way.
May I have access to the repository and the issue, to analyse the problem and propose a solution?

Answer (score 0):

project

- app

  - models
  - views
  - serializers
  - tasks
  - app_urls
  - settings
  - urls
  - etc etc...

models.py:

```
from .tasks import taskA
class Bag():
    ...

sender=Bag
def bag_signal():
    taskA()
```

views:

```
from .models import Bag
from .serializers import BagSerializer

class BagViewset(ModelViewSet):
    model = Bag
    serializer = BagSerializer
```

serializer:

```
from .models import Bag
class BagSerializer(ModelSerializer):
def meta:
    model = Bag

def validate():
    **validation stuff
```

tasks:

```
from django.apps import apps
def taskA():
    model_name = apps.get('app', 'model_name')
    model.objects.create(**data)
    # wanna call serializer's validate and save it through serializer.save()
```

Comment: It doesnt cause any problems if I import serializers in the task's  function.